# Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js' on online host

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Today I uploading my discord bot to an online host! I Installed on my files on to the ftp with out any errors. The host is Pebble Host. When Tried to Start the bot I got the error bellow. I tried starting the bot on my computer and it worked completely fine. I also installed all the modules. If you can help me that would be great. Thanks!

```
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] throw err;
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] ^
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] Require stack:
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] - /index.js
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] at Object.<anonymous> (/index.js:2:17)
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] requireStack: [ '/index.js' ]
01.09 21:00:30 [Bot] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Idk if still relevant but you need to run "npm install discord.js" from cmd https://discord.js.org/#/
(thought was important as is the top link on google search)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your `package.json` and in the dependencies section, add `"discord.js": "^12.3.0"` and every other packages you need. Then go to the terminal / console and type

```
npm install
```

While you're in the directory where your `index.js` file is located. This should fix the issue. Sometimes online hosts tend to have some issues with the npm installation, and they check your `package.json` rather than saving what you previously installed.
The possible issues are:

1. They reroute your require to their server rather than independently having a `node_modules` folder.
2. You didn't install it properly.
3. They don't use `npm`, but `pnpm`, having both at once tend to not work, use `pnpm` instead.
4. You didn't install the modules in your main folder (where your `index.js` is).
5. The host has some internal issues with their server and are unable to install the modules properly.